# Geometry Problem from Olympiad book

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, angle, triangle-inequality

Given the base and the vertical angle of a triangle show that its area is greatest when it's isoceles

I am stuck on how to proceed and which theorem to use here
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4219501/edit) the question and add what you tried and where you got stuck, before it gets summarily closed for a complete lack of context and own work.

Comment: What do you mean by "the vertical angle" ?

Comment: @WangYeFei - presumably the angle opposite the base

Answer (score 5):

Here is a hint you might be able to use

[image]

Comment: Thanks helped me solve it realized it was simple lol

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the formula cosines,
suppose the base to be a and the given angle A (opposite to each other), and the other two sides adjacent to angle A as x and y.
Now apply the formula cosines for angle A.
Now find $sinA$.
Then use$$0.5*x*y*sinA$$
Then AM-GM inequality on the term which you get in numerator.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $S = \dfrac{1}{2}ab\sin C$. Thus: $S \le \dfrac{1}{8}(a+b)^2\sin C$, with equality occur at $a = b$ which shows $\triangle ABC$ isosceles. To show that $S$ reaches a maximum value, you need to show: $(a+b)^2$ also reaches a maximum in terms of $c$. To this end, use the law of cosines: $c^2 = a^2+b^2 - 2ab\cos C= (a+b)^2 - 2ab(1+\cos C)\ge (a+b)^2 - \dfrac{1+\cos C}{2}(a+b)^2= \dfrac{1-\cos C}{2}(a+b)^2= \sin^2(\frac{C}{2})(a+b)^2\implies (a+b)^2 \le \dfrac{c^2}{\sin^2(\frac{C}{2})}\implies S \le \dfrac{1}{8}\cdot\dfrac{c^2}{\sin^2(\frac{C}{2})}\cdot \sin C= \dfrac{c^2}{4\tan(\frac{C}{2})}$. This is the maximum value of the area $S$ of $\triangle ABC$, and this value occurs when $a = b$ by AM-GM inequality. So $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles when the max occurs.